# Typescript and Prisma return values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prisma

I am using the T3 stack (create-t3-app) with Typescript, Prisma, and NextJS.  I'm having trouble getting the results from a query that I expect.  The model is a simple Article.

```
model Article {
    id              String      @id @default(cuid())
    organizationId  String
    title           String
    subtitle        String?
    content         String      @db.Text
    publishDate     DateTime?
    endDate         DateTime?
}
```

The type Article, which is automatically generated by Prisma, seems to be fine.  I can create objects, console log them, etc.  However, I can't seem to pass it to a React/NextJS functional component using props.

```
export const articleRouter = createTRPCRouter({
  getById: publicProcedure.input(z.string()).query(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
    const x = await ctx.prisma.article.findFirst({
      where: {
        id: input,
      },
    });

    return x;
  }),
});
```

My expectation would be that a findFirst() would return an object of type Article, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  In the snippet below the attribute "blue" is passed to ArticleCard fine and I can use it as expected.  However the Article object is of the wrong type according to a message I can't begin to decipher (all the way at the end of this post)

```
const article = api.article.getById.useQuery("clkem2k2m0000uf2klvuu7bfl");
...
<ArticleCard color="blue" article={article} />
```

```
import { Article } from "@prisma/client";

export interface ArticleProps {
  article: Article;
  color: string;
}

export default function ArticleCard(props: ArticleProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Box>
          INSIDE THE BOX
          <Card className="p-2">
            INSIDE THE CARD
            <Typography variant="h3" className="text-blue-500">
              {props.article.title} Yay! {props.color}
            </Typography>
            {props.article?.subtitle ? (
              <Typography variant="h5">{props.article?.subtitle}</Typography>
            ) : (
              <></>
            )}
            <Typography variant="body1">{props.article.content}</Typography>
          </Card>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

I think I have two questions.

1. What data type is findFirst() returning in this instance?
2. How do I properly pass it via props to the functional component?

THANKS!

Error message:

```
Type 'UseTRPCQueryResult<(GetResult<{ id: string; organizationId: string; title: string; subtitle: string | null; content: string; publishDate: Date | null; endDate: Date | null; }, unknown> & {}) | null, TRPCClientErrorLike<...>>' is not assignable to type 'GetResult<{ id: string; organizationId: string; title: string; subtitle: string | null; content: string; publishDate: Date | null; endDate: Date | null; }, unknown> & {}'.
  Type 'TRPCHookResult & QueryObserverRefetchErrorResult<(GetResult<{ id: string; organizationId: string; title: string; subtitle: string | null; content: string; publishDate: Date | null; endDate: Date | null; }, unknown> & {}) | null, TRPCClientErrorLike<...>>' is not assignable to type 'GetResult<{ id: string; organizationId: string; title: string; subtitle: string | null; content: string; publishDate: Date | null; endDate: Date | null; }, unknown> & {}'.
    Type 'TRPCHookResult & QueryObserverRefetchErrorResult<(GetResult<{ id: string; organizationId: string; title: string; subtitle: string | null; content: string; publishDate: Date | null; endDate: Date | null; }, unknown> & {}) | null, TRPCClientErrorLike<...>>' is missing the following properties from type 'GetResult<{ id: string; organizationId: string; title: string; subtitle: string | null; content: string; publishDate: Date | null; endDate: Date | null; }, unknown>': title, id, content, organizationId, and 3 more.ts(2322)
articleCard.tsx(5, 3): The expected type comes from property 'article' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ArticleProps'
(property) ArticleProps.article: GetResult<{
    id: string;
    organizationId: string;
    title: string;
    subtitle: string | null;
    content: string;
    publishDate: Date | null;
    endDate: Date | null;
}, unknown> & {}
```

Comment: The issue here appears to be related to how you're using the result from the useQuery hook in your tRPC client. The useQuery hook does not directly return the data from your API, but rather an object that includes several properties, including the data. So when you're trying to pass article as a prop to ArticleCard, you're actually passing an object with several properties, one of which is data that contains your article data.

Can you share what you are getting in the useQuery result?

Comment: Notice you're using `@db.Text` which is a PostgreSQL only datatype. If anyone wants to replicate your problem they'll have to set up the proper DBMS.

Comment: @Sebastian I think it's supported for MySQL also: [link](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mysql#native-type-mappings)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @mateoc15, however, if I create a new t3 app the default will be sqlite and I'll get an error, that's why I added the tag.